# How to use dictionary with dynamic value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic

OK, there is just something like this:

`Dictionary<string, dynamic>` object

And I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` object like this :

`{"great":"well","well":"WTF?",...}`

But `Dictionary<string, dynamic> dyndict = new Dictionary<string, string>()` is actually not available.

Is there some good way to assign the latter dict to the dynamic one?

Maybe I'll use a while loop? But what if have some variant `Dictionary<string, int>`or`Dictionary<string, MyObject>` or so on? Is there some method like `extend` in C#?

How can I be more elegant? (And that's why I choose C#! :) )

### **UPDATE1**

What I want to figure out is a **generic** way to extend my dynamic-value dictionary. Can **Extension Methods** help me out? Or am I wrong at the start point?

### **UPDATE2**

To be more specific, what I what is to achieve an auto duck-type dict......The `ToDictionary()` is also typed dict, I want to know wether there is a way like this:

`Dictionary<string, dynamic> dyndict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()`

`Dictionary<string, string> otherDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){...}`

`dyndict.extend(otherDict )`

ToDictionary(),right....Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to assign the values from `Dictionary<string,string>` to `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem.. do you want to convert a `Dictionary<string, string>` to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`?

Comment: You need to create a dictionary of the right type, and then copy over all the keys and values, the two types are not assignment compatible.

Comment: a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` is more or less equivalent to `Dictionary<string, object>` at runtime.

Comment: Nope, I know the  assignment is not right, but really, I'm trying to figure out a good way to avoid using handwriting loop to assign a specific typed dictionary to a dictionary with dynamic value. @dcastro@Bauss

Comment: See the duplicate question, use `ToDictionary` to cast the values to `dynamic`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, that perfectly true, but actually you don't know whether it provided a **struct** or simple-typed value in the dictionary.